# Customizing RStudio environment in Docker container

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I use RStudio in Docker container in Windows 10 Pro.
I use RStudio `rocker/rstudio` image pulled from https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/.

To start container I executed command:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v //c/Users/<My name>/Documents/R/Rprojects:/home/rstudio/ rocker/rstudio
```

And then I can access the server from my browser by following link:
http://localhost:8787/. Everything works fine.

What I want to do is some customization of the RStudio environment. In particular, I changed Tools/Global options/Editor theme to 'Pastel on Dark'. I applied this option but it persists only when the container alive. When I restart the container custom options are all gone.

My projects are saved in the folder that I indicated when running container, but global options are not.

So, how can I save also global options on my hard drive. Maybe I need to expose another folder on my drive which will connect to container folder where RStudio saves global options?

Is it possible to predefine  global options in `dockerfile` as a new layer in docker image?

Comment: I found the solution. RStudio creates special folders in the same drive that I mounted. So, If you restart the container with the same folder, all customizations are preserved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, like me, you use an ephemeral container (using the `--rm` flag), then the container gets deleted when stopped. This is a good thing as it ensures a 100% clean environment every time but it means settings are not preserved from session to session.

Unlike many popular IDE, rstudio settings are not stored in a user-accessible transparent json, although [they are working on it](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1607).

A workaround is copying over the settings to the right location:

- keybindings: `/home/rstudio/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_bindings.json`
- general settings (such as theme): `/home/rstudio/.rstudio/monitored/user-settings`

To set  it up:

1. Launch rstudio in a container
2. Set your desired settings
3. Back up the 2 files listed above somewhere on your host.
4. Copy over the config files every time you start rstudio - see script below.

I have created a quick launch shortcut pointing to the following script which is easily adapted. It starts a container named rstudio and copies over the settings I have backed up (in my case from `/home/asac/projects/rstudio-config`)

```sh
#!/bin/bash                                     
                         
echo Running rstudio on localhost:8787                 
docker run -d --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=<pwd> \                       
-v /home/asac/projects:/home/rstudio/projects \                          
-v /home/asac/data:/home/rstudio/data \                                  
--name rstudio asachet/shiny-dev                                         
                                                                         
echo Copying over rstudio settings                                       
docker exec rstudio mkdir /home/rstudio/.R/rstudio/keybindings -p        
docker cp /home/asac/projects/rstudio-config/user-settings rstudio:/home/rstudio/.rstudio/monitored/user-settings
docker cp /home/asac/projects/rstudio-config/rstudio_bindings.json rstudio:/home/rstudio/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_bindings.json
                                                                         
echo Launching browser                                                   
xdg-open http://localhost:8787
```

## NEW IN 2020

With RStudio v1.3, there is a new file `~/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json` which controls all of the settings. You can copy it between machines or hand-edit it.

More details [in the RStudio Server PR](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/5069) which got ported to RStudio in version 1.3.

Comment: As an alternative to copying, you can also map a volume to the `.config` folder, or mount a local folder as a bind. This can easily be combined with a docker-compose.yml in which this is configured. See here for more details:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume
I would recommend also thinking about mapping both the .config folder and the /etc/rstudio folder for more settings

Comment: I was trying -v /home/.config:/home/.config where /home/.config contains my personal rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json file on the host machine. Somehow I am not able to mount into /home/.config on the container.  I can mount this anywhere into /home/rstudio but not above. Any suggestions?

Comment: I resolved this issue. Didn't realize I needed to bind to home/rstudio/.config in the container

Answer (score 1):

To clear up Alexander's comment on his own post:

1. **Run your container**: docker run -p 8787:8787 -v /home/cummingssg/code:/home/rstudio/code  rocker/verse
2. **Go to localhost** and make changes in appearance of RStudio like usual
3. **Exit container**: Using control-C or docker stop
4. **Find name of previous container**: docker ps -a
5. **Restart container, and it will have the same appearance**: docker start container_name*

(*whichever recent item of step 4 has image rocker/verse)

Thanks, Alexander

Comment: The thing is that once you exit it, this configuration will be lost.