# Export/import RStudio user preferences, global setting, etc

Tags: r, ide, rstudio, settings

I found myself lately having to install `RStudio` over multiple computers.

While I found it possible to migrate/reinstall my packages, I couldn't find a way/script/package that deals with migrating user preferences such as `global options` and its sub options (appearance, pane layout, ect.).

I tried to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750866/rstudio-global-settings-options-export-import), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852637/how-to-clone-an-rstudio-environment-on-a-different-machine), and [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/223168827-Global-options-import-export-conifguration), but I wasn't able to find an answer.

## Edit

I found that I can use `rstudioapi` to change the theme ([link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes#switching-themes)). However, I still have other `global options` that I don't know how to export (e.g. pane layout, fonts).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667945/customizing-rstudio-environment-in-docker-container

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

There is a package now, supporting the feature:
https://github.com/pat-s/rstudioSettings,
requiring RStudio v1.4.162+.

Unfortunately, it is not officially supported by now, but you could consider a workaround.

**Feature request:**

As you can see here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1607, there are plenty of users waiting for this feature:

(related)  https://community.rstudio.com/t/configure-rstudio-global-options-on-install/14881

**Workaround:**

Here is described where the settings are stored: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State.

You can navigate to the `Rstudio-desktop` folder. E.g. on windows enter: `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop` in the explorer.

The global options you are looking for can be found here: `..\monitored\user-settings\user-settings`.

**Example:**

The flag "always save history,..." in `Rstudio - Tools - Global Options - General` is the first value in `..\monitored\user-settings\user-settings`.

So you might consider copying this folder as suggested here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000932128-RStudio-Config-Files?page=1#community_comment_115001435068.