# Export RStudio Appearance as a Theme File

Tags: r, export, themes, rstudio

Please note, I have read the posting [Export/import RStudio user preferences, global setting, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903423/export-import-rstudio-user-preferences-global-setting-etc) but I wasn't able to export the appearance settings.

I have a custom theme for RStudio installed on a machine and I would like to export it to use on another machine.

Is there a way that I can export the current theme/themes used by RSudio on my machine as a theme file (such as file with a `.rstheme` or `.theme` or `.tmTheme` extension etc.)?

Comment: Have you reviewed the RStudio documentation here: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html and here: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes They seem to cover the topic. What exactly did you try and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @MrFlick the documentation discusses importing a theme file or making a theme file from scratch. In my case, I'm on a workstation (without admin rights) and someone has installed a theme file on RStudio that I like, however they have deleted the `.theme` file they imported it from. Therefore I would like to somehow export the current theme that is being used. I have tried searching the folder structure to see where the themes are held but I think my lack of admin rights prevents me from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out too, the closest I can get is finding the file registry for *imported* themes only; it doesn't include RStudio's own themes, annoyingly.

> appdata/roaming/rstudio/themes on Windows
>
> c~/. config/rstudio/themes on mac